# Bootstrap When lowering resolution navbar overlaps logo and it gets messed up

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I am moving down to tablet resolution from 991px to the phone resolution, my menu items overlap the logo and everything gets messed up. I am still learning Bootstrap so I would need some help with it, I'd like to fix it and make it actually look good.
The worst part is that I will have to make 2 more list items at the end of the navbar, but this has already messed it up.

[image]

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mobile-menu">
                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand hidden-xs" id="logo" href="#"><img src="images/Logo.png" alt="Recipe Website"></a>
                <center><a class="navbar-brand visible-xs" id="logo-xs" href="#"><img src="images/Logo-xs.png" alt="Recipe Website"></a></center>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mobile-menu">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#" alt="Home">Home</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Recipes</a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a href="#">Appetizers</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Beverage</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Bread</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Fruit</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Meat</a></li>
                      </ul>
                  </li>                  
                  <li><a href="#" alt="Home">F.A.Q</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" alt="Home">Contact Us</a></li>
                  <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                  </form>
                  </form>


              </ul>



            </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

Comment: if you are using bootstrap provided CSS. then forget it. bootstrap is not that design oriented or compatible. Better you modify their CSS rather you write your own.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML pasted here looks fine: http://www.bootply.com/I7jobETm52

You should post your custom CSS too. Without seeing it, it's hard to know for sure, but I would bet is has something to do with `#logo` and `#logo-xs` which I am guessing you've customized. Do they have set `heights/widths/max/min/etc`?

If so, remove those, and let the size of the image itself dictate (presumably, that's why you have two sizes). Also `position`, `top`, `left`, could all contribute to this problem if you're using them. First test would be, kill those IDs from the html and if the problem goes away you know where to focus.

Otherwise, try killing the visible-xs/hidden-xs options for test. And finally, try pulling the visible-xs item out of `<center>` and just put it in a regular div (with class="center-block" if you must).

Comment: This is all I've got as custom CSS so far:body {
padding-top: 40px;
}

#navbar-top {
 height: 100px;

}

#logo {
 margin-top: -35px;
}

#logo-xs {
 margin-top: -35px;
}